# Add two SQL fields together in new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add together two numerical values in my database (STOCKVOLUME and UNITS) and insert the result into a different field in a column (NEWVAL). I want this code to do this for every row in the database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET NEWVAL = STOCKVOLUME + UNITS
```

Comment: +1, But I would add `ISNULL` there, just in case those columns are nullable

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert into another table :

```
INSERT INTO aTable(NEWVAL) SELECT (STOCKVOLUME + UNITS) FROM anotherTAble;
```

If you want to Update another filed of the same table :

```
UPDATE aTable SET NEWVAL = (STOCKVOLUME + UNITS);
```

Comment: **EDIT** And just as I post this you revise. ;-)